# solana-farm-ctrl: command not found

Tags: vault

Following the "Quick Start" instructions for deploying the farm, I started working with Fund. Conducted the build, which was successful (as well as the farm build). Next was the command: solana-farm-ctrl --keypair main_admin.json generate Fund [FUND_PROGRAM_ADDRESS] [FUND_NAME].
When I use the command I get the error: solana-farm-ctrl: command not found.
Tell me, please, what is the matter here?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `solana-farm-ctrl` isn't included in your path, which is why the shell can't find it.

If you look at the Quick Start docs at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/farms/docs/quick_start.md#build, they specifically call this out:

> Binaries will be placed under `solana-program-library/farms/target/release` directory. If you plan on using `solana-farm-ctrl` or `solana-farm-client` tools per the examples below, you might want to add the release path to your environment's `PATH` variable:

```
pushd target/release
export PATH=$PATH:$(pwd)
popd
```